# Excel VBA Macro to copy data between sheets when value appears in column then loops to next value

Tags: vba, excel

I have some experience of writing macros but this area is new to me. I have been working on a new project and have most parts of it working but I can't seem to get this part to work. I have looked at lookup and match range but none seem to work properly.

- Sheet "Master" = contains all the data in a large sheet with a number of columns including an ID column.
- Sheet "Projectx" = contains ID column I am searching for.

What I am trying to do is this.

1. Search ID from Column A "Projectx" in "Master" sheet Column A and if it exists then copy the entire row beside the value in "Projectx".
2. if copied or no match exist then move on to the next value until the column is blank.
3. this will then be expanded in the future to allow different files to be opened and searched from different suppliers.

Many thanks & I hope this makes sense

This was my attempt:

```
Sub Match()

On Error Resume Next  
Dim ID_upn As String  
Dim ID_Row As Long  
Dim ID_Clm As Long  

Table1 = Sheets("Projectx").Range("A2:A200") ' ID Column from Project sheet table  
Table2 = Sheets("Master").Range("A2:P200") ' Master Table  
ID_Row = Sheets("Projectx").Range("A2").row ' C2 is the first cell to start checking  
ID_Clm = Sheets("Master").Range("A2").Column
For Each cl In Table1  
  Sheets("Projectx").Cells(ID_Row, ID_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.if(cl, Table2, 3, False)  
  ID_Row = ID_Row + 1  
Next cl  
MsgBox "Done"  
End SubSub Match()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
Sub getFromMaster()
Dim row as Range, wb as Workbook, masterSheet as Worksheet, idSheet as Worksheet
Dim idVal as String, masterRow as Range, masterVal as String
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set masterSheet = wb.sheets("Master")
    Set idSheet = wb.sheets("Projectx")
    For each row in idSheet.usedrange.rows
        idVal = row.cells(1).value
        For each masterRow in masterSheet.usedrange.rows
            masterVal = masterRow.cells(1).value
            If masterVal = idVal then
                masterRow.copy row
                Exit For
            End if
        next 'masterRow
    next 'row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had been using if functions etc. but couldn't get it to work. Your way is far more clean.